# Store Ms Access data into javascript dataset

Tags: javascript, php, ms-access

I have a code that fetch all the data in MS Access database in php and its working.

```
$conn = odbc_connect('pivot_test','','') or die ("Error in connection");
$sql = "select * from empDetails"; 
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
   { exit ("Error in Sql");}
    echo "<table><tr>";
    echo "<th>id</th>";
    echo "<th>year</th>";
    echo "<th>month</th>";
    echo "<th>empName</th>";
    echo "<th>empPos</th>";
    echo "<th>numMc</th>";
    echo "<th>numLeave</th></tr>";
    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
    {
    $id = odbc_result($rs,"id");
    $year = odbc_result($rs,"year");
    $month = odbc_result($rs,"month");
    $empName = odbc_result($rs,"empName");
    $empPose = odbc_result($rs,"empPos");
    $numMc = odbc_result($rs,"numMc");
    $numLeave = odbc_result($rs,"numLeave");
    }
    odbc_close($conn);
    echo"</table>";
    ?>
```

But now I need to store all the data in the dataset something like this:

```
var pivot_dataset = [
{"id": 1, "year": 2014 , "month": "JAN", "empName": "David", "empPos": "engineer", "numMc": 1, "numLeave": 2},
];
```

How to do this?please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method. It returns a JSON string if you pass it an associative array.

```
<?php

$conn = odbc_connect('pivot_test','','') or die ("Error in connection");
$sql = "select * from empDetails"; 
$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

if (!$rs)
   exit ("Error in Sql");

echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>id</th>";
echo "<th>year</th>";
echo "<th>month</th>";
echo "<th>empName</th>";
echo "<th>empPos</th>";
echo "<th>numMc</th>";
echo "<th>numLeave</th></tr>";

$pivot_dataset = array();
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    // Push this data onto the end of the array
    $pivot_dataset[] = array(
        'id' => odbc_result($rs,"id"),
        'year' => odbc_result($rs,"year"),
        'month' => odbc_result($rs,"month"),
        'empName' => odbc_result($rs,"empName"),
        'empPose' => odbc_result($rs,"empPos"),
        'numMc' => odbc_result($rs,"numMc"),
        'numLeave' => odbc_result($rs,"numLeave")
    );
}

odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";

$jsonStr = json_encode($pivot_dataset);

// var pivot_dataset = [{"id": 1, "year": 2014 , "month": "JAN" ... }, { ... }];
echo "var pivot_dataset = $jsonStr;";
```

Comment: Are you needing to print out a JSON string in Javascript, or are you wanting to store this data in php?

Comment: TQ triad, but then how can we attach the $jsonStr to the javascript dataset?

Comment: Yes, i need to store the data in dataset javascript.

Comment: I updated my post with a solution that generates an array of json objects.

Comment: I've tried this code but then I got this error  "Call to undefined function json_encode()" . Do u have any idea?

Comment: What version of php are you using? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php says you need to be using PHP 5 >= 5.2.0